не могу понять как, сделать чтобы на сайте переводился весь текст
не переводится текст который открывается по нажатию на блоки главная, наша команда, контакты, наши услуги, весь остальной, на основной странице переводится.
я не претендую на крутую разработку сайтов, просто понадобилась единоразово сайт сделать,
помогите пожалуйста
html
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Pop HTML CSS Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tooplate-style.css">

    <script>
        document.documentElement.className = "js";
        var supportsCssVars = function () {
            var e, t = document.createElement("style");
            t.innerHTML = "root: { --tmp-var: bold; }", document.head.appendChild(t);
            e = !!(window.CSS && window.CSS.supports && window.CSS.supports("font-weight", "var(--tmp-var)"));
            t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
            return e;
        };
        supportsCssVars() || alert("Пожалуйста, используйте современный браузер, например, последнюю версию Chrome или Microsoft Edge.");
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <label for="language" id="language" data-lang="lang">Выберите язык:</label>
        <select id="language-selector" onchange="changeLanguage(this.value)">
            <option value="ru">Русский</option>
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="kk">Қазақша</option>
            <option value="ky">Кыргызча</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="img-ab">
        <img src="img/ab.png" alt="Описание изображения" class="img-ab">
    </div>

    <div id="tm-bg"></div>
    <div id="tm-wrap">
        <div class="tm-main-content">
            <div class="container tm-site-header-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-md-col-xl-6 mb-md-0 mb-sm-4 mb-4 tm-site-header-col">
                        <div class="tm-site-header">
                            <h1 class="mb-4" data-lang="welcome">AB energo</h1>
                            <img src="img/underline.png" class="img-fluid mb-4">
                            <p id="p1" data-lang="p1">Компания занимается оптовой и розничной продажей электроэнергии для юридических лиц в целях энергоснабжения.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="grid">
                                <div class="grid__item" id="home-link" data-lang="home-link">
                                    <div class="product">
                                        <div class="tm-nav-link" onclick="toggleDescription('home-description')">
                                            <i class="fas fa-home fa-3x tm-nav-icon"></i>
                                            <span class="tm-nav-text" data-lang="span">Главная</span>
                                            <div class="product__bg"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product__description" id="home-description" style="display: none;">
                                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    <h2 class="tm-page-title" id="h2a1" data-lang="h2a1">Добро пожаловать в АБ Энерго</h2>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                                    <img src="img/welcome-3.jpg" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                                                    <p data-lang="p2">Мы предоставляем высококачественное энергоснабжение для вашего бизнеса.</p>
                                                    <p data-lang="p3">Нам важен каждый клиент, и мы стремимся обеспечивать надёжность и стабильность поставок. <a rel="nofollow" href="https://vk.com" target="_parent" data-lang="media1">Мы в социальных сетях</a>. Ваша обратная связь помогает нам становиться лучше.</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                                    <p data-lang="p4">Если у вас есть вопросы или предложения, мы готовы выслушать вас.</p>
                                                    <p data-lang="p5">Для вопросов и предложений обращайтесь через <a rel="nofollow" href="https://vk.com" target="_parent">форму</a> обратной связи.</p>
                                                    <img src="img/welcome-4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="grid__item" id="team-link">
                                    <div class="product">
                                        <div class="tm-nav-link" onclick="toggleDescription('team-description')">
                                            <i class="fas fa-users fa-3x tm-nav-icon"></i>
                                            <span class="tm-nav-text" data-lang="span2">Наша команда</span>
                                            <div class="product__bg"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product__description" id="team-description" style="display: none;">
                                            <div class="p-sm-4 p-2">
                                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                                    <div class="col-12">
                                                        <h2 class="tm-page-title" data-lang="h2a2">Наша команда</h2>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row tm-reverse-sm">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
                                                        <p class="mb-4" data-lang="p6">Наша команда состоит из высококвалифицированных специалистов, обладающих богатым опытом в области энергоснабжения. Мы стремимся предоставлять качественные услуги и решения, которые соответствуют требованиям наших клиентов.</p>
                                                        <p class="mb-4" data-lang="p7">Каждый из наших сотрудников имеет опыт работы как с крупными, так и с небольшими предприятиями, что позволяет нам эффективно управлять поставками электроэнергии.</p>
                                                        <p class="mb-5" data-lang="p8">Мы уверены, что успех нашей компании зависит от профессионализма и преданности нашей команды.</p>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-lang="a1">Читать далее</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-lg-0 mb-sm-4 mb-4">
                                                        <img src="img/team.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="grid__item" id="services-link">
                                    <div class="product">
                                        <div class="tm-nav-link" onclick="toggleDescription('services-description')">
                                            <i class="fas fa-handshake fa-3x tm-nav-icon"></i>
                                            <span class="tm-nav-text" data-lang="span3">Наши услуги</span>
                                            <div class="product__bg"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product__description" id="services-description" style="display: none;">
                                            <div class="p-sm-4 p-2">
                                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                                    <div class="col-12">
                                                        <h2 class="tm-page-title" data-lang="h2a3">Наши услуги</h2>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                                    <div class="col-12">
                                                        <p data-lang="p9">Мы предлагаем комплексные решения в области энергоснабжения, включая управление поставками электроэнергии, оптимизацию затрат и поддержку стабильности поставок. Наша команда профессионалов обеспечивает высокое качество услуг и индивидуальный подход к каждому клиенту.</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="grid__item" id="contact-link">
                                    <div class="product">
                                        <div class="tm-nav-link" onclick="toggleDescription('contact-description')">
                                            <i class="fas fa-comments fa-3x tm-nav-icon"></i>
                                            <span class="tm-nav-text" data-lang="span4">Контакты</span>
                                            <div class="product__bg"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product__description" id="contact-description" style="display: none;">
                                            <div class="pt-sm-4 pb-sm-4 pl-sm-5 pr-sm-5 pt-2 pb-2 pl-3 pr-3">
                                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                                    <div class="col-12">
                                                        <h2 class="tm-page-title" data-lang="h2a4">Свяжитесь с нами</h2>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row mb-4">
                                                    <div class="col-12">
                                                        <p data-lang="p10">Мы готовы ответить на ваши вопросы и предложения. Пожалуйста, заполните форму ниже, и мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время.</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-12">
                                                        <form action="index.html" method="post" class="contact-form">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                                                    <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required/>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 tm-col-email">
                                                                    <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required/>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <textarea id="contact_message" name="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="9" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary tm-btn-submit" data-lang="submit">Отправить</button>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <p class="small tm-copyright-text" data-lang="p11">&copy; <span class="tm-current-year">2024</span> АБ Энерго. Все права защищены. INFO: <a rel="nofollow" href="https://vk.com" class="tm-text-highlight">link</a></p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        const texts = {
            ru: {
                welcome: "AB energo",
                description: "Компания занимается оптовой и розничной продажей электроэнергии для юридических лиц в целях энергоснабжения.",
                span: "Главная",
                h2a1: "Добро пожаловать в АБ Энерго",
                h2a2: "Наша команда",
                h2a3: "Наши услуги",
                h2a4: "Свяжитесь с нами",
                lang: "Выберите язык:",
                media1: "Мы в социальных сетях!",
                p1: "Компания занимается оптовой и розничной продажей электроэнергии для юридических лиц в целях энергоснабжения.",
                p2: "Мы предоставляем высококачественное энергоснабжение для вашего бизнеса.",
                p3: "Нам важен каждый клиент, и мы стремимся обеспечивать надёжность и стабильность поставок. Ваша обратная связь помогает нам становиться лучше.",
                p4: "Если у вас есть вопросы или предложения, мы готовы выслушать вас.",
                p5: "Для вопросов и предложений обращайтесь через форму обратной связи.",
                p6: "Наша команда состоит из высококвалифицированных специалистов, обладающих богатым опытом в области энергоснабжения.",
                p7: "Каждый из наших сотрудников имеет опыт работы как с крупными, так и с небольшими предприятиями.",
                p8: "Мы уверены, что успех нашей компании зависит от профессионализма и преданности нашей команды.",
                p9: "Мы предлагаем комплексные решения в области энергоснабжения, включая управление поставками электроэнергии, оптимизацию затрат и поддержку стабильности поставок. Наша команда профессионалов обеспечивает высокое качество услуг и индивидуальный подход к каждому клиенту.",
                p10: "Мы готовы ответить на ваши вопросы и предложения. Пожалуйста, заполните форму ниже, и мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время.",
                p11: "&copy; <span class='tm-current-year'>2024</span> АБ Энерго. Все права защищены.",
                submit: "Отправить"
            },
            en: {
                welcome: "AB energo",
                description: "The company is engaged in wholesale and retail sale of electricity for legal entities for energy supply.",
                span: "Home",
                h2a1: "Welcome to AB Energo",
                h2a2: "Our Team",
                h2a3: "Our Services",
                h2a4: "Contact Us",
                lang: "Choose language:",
                media1: "We are on social media!",
                p1: "The company is engaged in wholesale and retail sale of electricity for legal entities for energy supply.",
                p2: "We provide high-quality energy supply for your business.",
                p3: "Every client is important to us, and we strive to ensure reliability and stability of supplies. Your feedback helps us improve.",
                p4: "If you have any questions or suggestions, we are ready to listen to you.",
                p5: "For questions and suggestions, please contact us through the feedback form.",
                p6: "Our team consists of highly qualified specialists with extensive experience in energy supply.",
                p7: "Each of our employees has experience working with both large and small enterprises.",
                p8: "We believe the success of our company depends on the professionalism and dedication of our team.",
                p9: "We offer comprehensive solutions in energy supply, including energy supply management, cost optimization, and supply stability support. Our team of professionals ensures high quality services and an individual approach to each client.",
                p10: "We are ready to answer your questions and suggestions. Please fill out the form below, and we will contact you shortly.",
                p11: "&copy; <span class='tm-current-year'>2024</span> AB Energo. All rights reserved.",
                submit: "Submit"
            },
            kk: {
                welcome: "AB energo",
                description: "Біз энергиямен жабдықтау қызметтерін ұсынамыз.",
                span: "Басты",
                h2a1: "AB Energo-ға қош келдіңіз",
                h2a2: "Біздің команда",
                h2a3: "Біздің қызметтер",
                h2a4: "Бізбен байланысыңыз",
                lang: "Тілді таңдаңыз:",
                media1: "Біз әлеуметтік желілердеміз!",
                p1: "Компания заңды тұлғаларға энергиямен жабдықтау мақсатында электр энергиясын көтерме және бөлшек саудада сатады.",
                p2: "Біз сіздің бизнесіңіз үшін жоғары сапалы энергиямен жабдықтауды қамтамасыз етеміз.",
                p3: "Әр клиент біз үшін маңызды, біз жеткізілімдердің сенімділігі мен тұрақтылығын қамтамасыз етуге тырысамыз. Сіздің пікіріңіз бізге жақсартуға көмектеседі.",
                p4: "Сұрақтарыңыз немесе ұсыныстарыңыз болса, біз сізді тыңдауға дайынбыз.",
                p5: "Сұрақтар мен ұсыныстар үшін бізге кері байланыс формасы арқылы хабарласыңыз.",
                p6: "Біздің команда энергиямен жабдықтау саласында бай тәжірибесі бар жоғары білікті мамандардан тұрады.",
                p7: "Біздің әрбір қызметкеріміз ірі және шағын кәсіпорындармен жұмыс істеген тәжірибесіне ие.",
                p8: "Біз компаниямыздың табысы біздің командамыздың кәсібилігі мен адалдығына байланысты деп сенеміз.",
                p9: "Біз энергиямен жабдықтау саласында кешенді шешімдерді ұсынамыз, соның ішінде энергиямен жабдықтауды басқару, шығындарды оңтайландыру және жеткізілімдердің тұрақтылығын қамтамасыз ету. Біздің мамандар командасы жоғары сапалы қызметтерді және әр клиентке жеке көзқарасты қамтамасыз етеді.",
                p10: "Сұрақтарыңыз бен ұсыныстарыңыз болса, бізге жауап беруге дайынбыз. Төмендегі форманы толтырыңыз, және біз сізбен жақын арада хабарласамыз.",
                p11: "&copy; <span class='tm-current-year'>2024</span> AB Energo. Барлық құқықтар қорғалған.",
                submit: "Жіберу"
            },
            ky: {
                welcome: "AB energo",
                description: "Биз энергия менен камсыздоо кызматтарын сунуштайбыз.",
                span: "Башкы",
                h2a1: "AB Energo-га кош келиңиз",
                h2a2: "Биздин команда",
                h2a3: "Биздин кызматтар",
                h2a4: "Биз менен байланыш",
                lang: "Тилди тандаңыз:",
                media1: "Биз социалдык тармактардабыз!",
                p1: "Компания мыйзамдуу жактарга энергия менен камсыздоо максатында электр энергиясын оптом жана бөлшөктөн сатуу менен алектенет.",
                p2: "Биз сиздин бизнес үчүн жогорку сапаттагы энергия менен камсыздоону сунуштайбыз.",
                p3: "Ар бир клиент биз үчүн маанилүү, биз жеткирүүнүн ишенимдүүлүгүн жана туруктуулугун камсыздоого аракет кылабыз. Сиздин пикирлериңиз бизге жакшыртууга жардам берет.",
                p4: "Эгерде сизде суроолор же сунуштар болсо, биз сизди угууга даярбыз.",
                p5: "Суроолор жана сунуштар үчүн бизге байланыш формасы аркылуу кайрылыңыз.",
                p6: "Биздин команда энергия менен камсыздоо тармагында бай тажрыйбасы бар жогорку квалификациялуу адистерден турат.",
                p7: "Биздин ар бир кызматкерибиз ири жана кичи ишканалар менен иштөө тажрыйбасына ээ.",
                p8: "Биз компаниябыздын ийгилиги биздин команданын кесипкөйлүгү жана берилгендигине көз каранды деп ишенебиз.",
                p9: "Биз энергия менен камсыздоо тармагында комплекстүү чечимдерди сунуштайбыз, анын ичинде энергия менен камсыздоону башкаруу, чыгымдарды оптималдаштыруу жана жеткирүүнүн туруктуулугун камсыздоо. Биздин адистер командасы жогорку сапаттагы кызматтарды жана ар бир кардарга индивидуалдуу мамилени камсыз кылат.",
                p10: "Суроолоруңуз же сунуштарыңыз болсо, биз сизге жооп берүүгө даярбыз. Төмөнкү форманы толтуруңуз, жана биз сиз менен жакын арада байланышабыз.",
                p11: "&copy; <span class='tm-current-year'>2024</span> AB Energo. Бардык укуктар корголгон.",
                submit: "Жөнөтүү"
            }
        };

        function changeLanguage(language) {
            console.log("Changing language to: " + language);
            document.querySelectorAll("[data-lang]").forEach(el => {
                const key = el.getAttribute("data-lang");
                if (texts[language][key]) {
                    console.log("Updating: " + key + " to " + texts[language][key]);
                    el.innerHTML = texts[language][key];
                } else {
                    console.warn("Key not found: " + key);
                }
            });
        }

        function toggleDescription(descriptionId) {
            const description = document.getElementById(descriptionId);
            description.style.display = description.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            changeLanguage('ru'); // Устанавливаем язык по умолчанию
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

js в яндекс диске тк не помещается по символам в вопросе
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/r28qK-HJTVLaNg

Нужен код javascript

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Что из этого отображается по нажатию, а что нет? Какой именно текст у вас не переводится?

обновил вопрос, приложил файлы js  и другие

Слегка модифицировал Вашу функцию changeLanguage на jQuery (на pureJS перепишите сами). Если будете использовать ее - не забудьте подключить jQuery
        function changeLanguage(language) {
            //Проверяем, что в объекте с переводами есть выбранный язык
            if ( typeof texts[language] !== 'undefined' ) {
                //Проверяем, что у нас есть хоть один элемент с атрибутом "data-lang"
                if ( $('[data-lang]').length > 0 ) {
                    //Находим все элементы с дата-атрибутом "data-lang" и перебираем их по-одному
                    $('[data-lang]').each(function () {
                        
                        //Извлекаем значение атрибута "data-lang"
                        var val = $(this).attr('data-lang');
                        //Проверяем, что в объекте с выбранным переводом есть такой есть перевод для такого значения
                        if (typeof (texts[language][val]) !== 'undefined') {
                            //Применяем перевод к элементу
                            $(this).html(texts[language][val]);
                        } else {
                            console.log($(this).get(0));
                            console.log('ОШИБКА: Не найден перевод по ключу "'+val+'"!');
                        }
                    });
                } else { console.log('ОШИБКА: страница не содержит ни одного элемента с атрибутом "data-lang"!'); }
            } else { console.log('ОШИБКА: объект переводов пуст или не существует!'); }
        }


В итоге видим в консоли такие ошибки
<div class="grid__item" id="home-link" data-lang="home-link"></div>
ОШИБКА: Не найден перевод по ключу "home-link"!
<span class=​"tm-nav-text" data-lang=​"span2">​Наша команда​</span>​
ОШИБКА: Не найден перевод по ключу "span2"!
<button class=​"btn btn-primary" data-lang=​"a1">​Читать далее​</button>​
ОШИБКА: Не найден перевод по ключу "a1"!
<span class=​"tm-nav-text" data-lang=​"span3">​Наши услуги​</span>​
ОШИБКА: Не найден перевод по ключу "span3"!
<span class=​"tm-nav-text" data-lang=​"span4">​Контакты​</span>​
ОШИБКА: Не найден перевод по ключу "span4"!

Идем в объект с переводами и проверяем какие же там есть ключи
["welcome", "description", "span", "h2a1", "h2a2", "h2a3", "h2a4", "lang", "media1", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11", "submit"]

Действительно, ключей
["home-link", "span2", "a1", "span3", "span4"] 

там нет
Делаем простой вывод: нужно поменять значения атрибута data-lang у тех элементов, что не переводятся на соответствующие из объекта переводов - т.е для "Наша команда" c data-lang="span2" на data-lang="h2a2" и так далее, либо поменять значения ключей в объекте переводов с соответствующим переводом на те, что указаны в data-lang у нужных элементов - т.е h2a2: "Наша команда" на span2: "Наша команда" и тд.
